# Any idea why new StringCollection().AddRange( SomeStringArray[]) throws an error?

Tags: addrange, stringcollection

I just stumbled across this:

```
new StringCollection().AddRange(SomeStringArray[])
```

throws an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection'"

but...

```
StringCollection x = new new StringCollection()
x.AddRange(SomeStringArray[])
```

Is perfectly fine. Combined, it's the exact same net result, no?

(.Net 7, C# 10)

I'm not seeing any mistakes with the syntax. Does anyone have any ideas why?

Split 1 line into 2 lines to avoid the error